# Mongoid: Relations always gives foreign_key value of nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm new to MongoDB and somewhat new to Rails. I work almost entirely in JavaEE and am trying to branch out. I found a problem to solve: My friends want to manage their D&D characters online but don't like any of the current tools. Sounds like a relatively simple app.

I've added devise to login, and decided to give MongoDB a shot with the Mongoid gem. After some reading and a few tutorials I've generated my app, and can add characters and login/sign up. My problem is thus: when I define a  user relationship of `has_many :characters` in the user model and a `belongs_to :user` in the character model I keep getting a returned value of `nil` in the record when it saves.  I believe I have it setup correctly, and any help would be appreciated.

user.rb(truncated for relevance)

```
  class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              :type => String, :default => ""
  field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :default => ""
  validates_presence_of :email, :encrypted_password

  index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
  field :name, type: String
  validates_presence_of :name

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
  :remember_me, :created_at, :updated_at

  ## Mappings
  has_many :characters
end
```

character.rb(truncated for relevance)

```
class Character
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :character_name, type: String
  field :level, type: Integer
  field :experience, type: Integer
  field :str, type: Integer
  field :con, type: Integer
  field :dex, type: Integer
  field :int, type: Integer
  field :wis, type: Integer
  field :cha, type: Integer
  field :editable, type: Boolean

  belongs_to :cduser
end
```

console output

```
    1.9.3p448 :005 > Character.first
     => #<Character _id: 5201b4e76e9552c74a000002, character_name: "Test",
level: 1, experience: 1, str: 1, con: 1, dex: 1, int: 1, wis: 1, cha: 1,
editable: false, user_id: nil> 
    1.9.3p448 :006 > User.first
   => #<User _id: 5201b4aa6e95523fa4000001, created_at: 2013-08-07 02:44:58 UTC,
updated_at: 2013-08-07 02:44:58 UTC, email: "test@gmail.com", encrypted_password:
"$2a$10$SKlgfRDPYkloYP/Re6ZF2evBx1PEzRsE8JVPVhvdkLe3p0bSIcjX.", 
reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil,
sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: 2013-08-07 02:44:58 UTC, 
last_sign_in_at: 2013-08-07 02:4

4:58 UTC, current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", 
          last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", name: "Zach">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your character model it should be `belongs_to :cduser, :class_name => "User"` instead of only this `belongs_to :cduser`, as rails is not able to identify for which class it belongs due to its naming convention.